# Kendo MVVM- using data-show to bind a layout

Tags: jquery, layout, mvvm, kendo-ui, show

I am using Kendo UI with JQuery to create a cross platform mobile application using Telerik appBuilder.

My question is about what is possible in Kendo. In seperate HTML files I have a layout definition and the view that loads the layout. In the view I am trying to us data-show to call a function that binds the layout in the ViewModel that the view links to as described in this blog post: http://codingwithspike.wordpress.com/2012/12/31/kendo-mobile-gotchas-tips-tricks/

My question is this: can I have the show function inside the View Model or do I have to put the show function outside of the View Model. Either way I have so far been unsuccessful in calling the function. and binding the model

I am trying to use the function in the footer of the layout, but I am having trouble binding the layout to the View Model.

I will include the code involved to hopefully clear up any questions.

this is the layout in my index.html file

```
<div data-role="layout" data-id="live-album-layout">
    <header data-role="header">
       <div data-role="navbar">
        <a data-role="backbutton" data-align="left">Back</a>
            <span data-role="view-title"></span>
            <a data-role="button" data-align="right" data-icon="home" href="views/home.html"></a>
        </div>
    </header>
    <footer data-role="footer">
        <div data-role="navbar">
            <a id="capture-button" data-role="button" data-bind="click: capturePhoto" data-align="left">Take Picture</a>
            <a id="get-photo-button" data-role="button" data-bind="click: getPhoto" data-align="right">Add From Library</a>
        </div>
    </footer>
</div>
```

Next is the View that I am trying to connect the data-binds to

```
<div id="livealbumView" data-role="view" data-layout="live-album-layout" 
data-title="Live Album" data-model="app.liveAlbum.viewModel"
data-stretch="true" data-show="app.LiveAlbum._loadLayoutMVVM">
    <div id="album-scroll-view" data-role="scrollview" data-items-per-page="4"
        data-content-height="100%" data-enable-pager="true"
        data-bind="source: galleryDataSource" data-template="scrollview-gallery-template">
    </div>
```

The template for the view is unimportant in this question. I know it works and I have a lot of changing to do on it anyway once I get this problem fixed.

Now, the View Model's Javascript

```
(function(global) {
var app = global.app = global.app || {};

var LiveAlbum = kendo.observable({
    currentId: 0,


    _loadLayoutMVVM: function() {
        alert("bound");
        kendo.bind($("#live-album-layout"), this);
    },


    onPhotoURISuccess: function(imageURI) {
        setTimeout( function() {
        LiveAlbum.addPicture(imageURI);
       }, 0);
    },
    capturePhoto: function() {
        // Take picture using device camera and retrieve image as base64-encoded string
        navigator.camera.getPicture(LiveAlbum.onPhotoURISuccess, LiveAlbum.onFail, { quality: 45,
            destinationType: Camera.DestinationType.FILE_URI,
            saveToPhotoAlbum:true});
    },
    getPhoto: function() {
        // Retrieve image file location from specified source
        navigator.camera.getPicture(LiveAlbum.onPhotoURISuccess, LiveAlbum.onFail, { quality: 45, 
            destinationType: Camera.DestinationType.FILE_URI,
            sourceType: Camera.PictureSourceType.PHOTOLIBRARY });
    },
    onFail: function(message) {
        if (message !== "no image selected") {
        setTimeout(function() {
            alert('Failed because ' + message);
        }, 0);
            }
    },
    galleryDataSource: new kendo.data.DataSource({
         type: "odata",
            transport: {
                read: {
                    url: "http://demos.telerik.com/kendo-ui/service/Northwind.svc/Products"
                }
            },
            serverPaging: true,
            pageSize: 30
    }),

    //change this function for uploading to the server
    addPicture: function(src) {
        this.currentId++;
        this.galleryDataSource.add({
            id: this.currentId,
            image_url:src
        })
        this.galleryDataSource.sync();
    }
});

app.liveAlbum = {
    viewModel: LiveAlbum
};
```

}(window))

and the app.js just for clarification

```
(function(global) {
var app = global.app = global.app || {};

document.addEventListener("deviceready", function() {
    app.application = new kendo.mobile.Application(document.body, {
        initial: "views/home.html",
        skin: "flat",
        transition: "slide"
    }, false);  
});
```

})(window);

Apologize that the "(window);" apparently is not cooperating with StackOverflow's formatting.

Any help is figuring out the limits of Kendo or even a hack solution would be helpful.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From this code:

```
var app = global.app = global.app || {};

var LiveAlbum = kendo.observable({
    _loadLayoutMVVM: function() { ... }
});

app.liveAlbum = {
    viewModel: LiveAlbum
};
```

It looks like your function will be located at:

```
app.liveAlbum.viewModel._loadLayoutMVVM
```

But your HTML contains:

```
data-show="app.LiveAlbum._loadLayoutMVVM"
```

---

Also in your `_loadLayoutMVVM` function, you are using a jQuery selector by element ID to locate your layout:

```
$("#live-album-layout")
```

But the actual layout element doesn't have (and shouldn't have) an ID. It does have a `data-id` though, so you could use the selector:

```
$("[data-id='live-album-layout']")
```

---

You should also make sure to only call `kendo.bind()` the first time your view's `show` event is called, not every time, or else the bindings will get duplicated and cause other weird update and performance issues. You can usually just do this by setting a boolean variable to `true` after you call `kendo.bind()` the first time, then don't call it again if the variable is `true`

---

Hope that helps, and thanks for reading my blog!

Comment: Your blog helped me a lot in understanding Kendo, even more than their demos and API references. I wish I had read it before I started diving into their resources and screwing up a lot, rewriting multiple times, and getting really frustrated a few times.